# Want to repair Grub

Tags: 12.04, installation, grub2, windows

I have ubuntu 12.04 and windows 8 installed on my system. The main boot manager is grub, also the ubuntu and windows are installed in separate partitions. I want to install windows 7 back in place of windows 8, but i want to repair grub ,so that ubuntu and windows 7 will work fine. Please help Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm.. well, the answer is dependent on a couple of things:

1. Did you upgrade from 7 to 8?  I'm not proficient on this for sure between 7/8, but if so, most previous versions of Windows allowed upgrades to be uninstalled/undone.  That may be your easiest route, and can be found in the Control Panel.  Otherwise..
2. If you did a full install onto an empty partition/overwritten, it's likely that you'll need to do that same step, but only using Windows 7 discs.  There's a small problem - depending on your boot method, though.  You may have to fallback upon boot-repair to correct any issues if they arise.

Let us know how you got to Windows 8 first, and we can take it from there..